# listview not refresh even after calling restart loader

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-loadermanager

I have List fragment with Context menu on long press of list item. The list item clicked and the list item removed from my Database. But the list not refresh even after calling restart loader?

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setEmptyText("Loading...");

        myAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.my_list_item, null,  new String[] {DBConstants.NAME,DBConstants.ITEM1,DBConstants.SYMBOL}, new int[] {R.id.my_companyname,R.id.my_item1,R.id.my_symbol},0);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        MyLoader = getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        DBHelper dbHelper=new DBHelper(getActivity());
        return new MyLoader(getActivity(),dbHelper);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) {
        if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0){
            myAdapter.swapCursor(c);
            if (isResumed()) {
                setListShown(true);
            } else {
                setListShownNoAnimation(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            setEmptyText("Not selected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        myAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String selectedItem = item.getTitle().toString();
        Log.i("context", "selected context menu item->"+selectedItem);

        if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("Remove"))
        {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo=(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
            String[] args={String.valueOf(menuInfo.id)};
            Log.i("context", String.valueOf(menuInfo.id));
            new DBHelper(getActivity()).getWritableDatabase().delete(DBConstants.MYSTOCKS_TABLE, "_ID=?", args);

            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);

            /*
             Cursor cursor = myAdapter.getCursor();
            myAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            */
            //getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        //super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mystocks_context, menu);

    }
```

Comment: Did you test to see if the `onLoadFinished` receives some valid data after you restart the `Loader`?

Comment: I removed if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0)-if else statement in onLoadFinished. Now it swaps cursor and refresh list.But now I initialized loader in onActivityCreated,it sometimes called onLoadFinished without calling onCreateLoader.

Comment: The `onLoadFinished` can't be called without `onCreateLoader` being previously called. Is there any reason to call the `getActivity().getLoaderManager()...` and storing the `Loader`? Just call `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);`.

Comment: Actually i have tabs and its contents as fragments. Whenever i add an item in tab1 content it will reflect on  tab2 content. On First time when activity created,if select an item in Tab1, it reflects in tab2. But next time i move to tab1 and select another item,it will not reflect on Tab2(Because of loader initialized in onActivitycreated.Now i replaced fragments only).I tried to initialize loader in onCreate but it says Content View not created still.i have swap cursor adapter in Load finished.

Comment: Without seeing your code regarding how you manipulate those fragment I would say to have a boolean field in the tab2 fragment which should indicate a need for a loader restart(in the `onResume` method) and update that field from tab1 fragment whenever you change its data.

Comment: Yes I initialized loader if not exists,else if already exists i restart it.Now it works great...

Answer (score 0):

Do you add the fragment in activity's onCreate or onResume? If the latter, you might want to move the fragment setup (transaction creation, addition of the fragment, committing) to onCreate. After doing that restartLoader() will work properly.